# RPi 4 intermittently connecting to SSH and VCN?

Tags: ssh, pi-4, vnc

I am using Raspian Buster on RPi4 and have enabled VNC on RPi. I am using windows 10 and connecting to PC and RPi using mobile hotspot on my Samsung Android.

The problem I am facing is the VNC  and SSH are intermittently connecting to RPi and then the connection drops after a few seconds and then I cannot connect at all.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- The same result if you connect devices to another AP?

Comment: Hotspots are NOT routers.

Comment: @Milliways I keep hearing that. What's the difference?